# Android scrolling makes whole screen blue

Tags: android, scroll, highlight

I have not been able to replicate this, but is anyone aware of what might cause the entire screen on an Android device to go light blue? It seems related to selecting a radio buttons and then scrolling. It happens on Nexus 5x with Android 8.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I have only heard of one other instance of this occurring. Could it be device specific? Strangely enough, once it happens it seem to stay this way, though the user says it is somewhat intermittent.

**Update:**

This only seems to happen on Android 8, if that helps anyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I eventually found the offending code. I verified this is only happening on Android 8 devices, maybe only Samsung? The offending code was:

```
    mFormScrollView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
        mFormScrollView.setFocusable(true);
        mFormScrollView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        // Hide the keyboard when moving the screen up or down. This should only
        // be an issue when
        // on a text edit field. Also disable focus jump using
        // "requestFocusFromTouch"
        mFormScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Utilities.hideKeyBoard(FormActivity.this, view);
                }
                // Keeps screen from jumping to nearest EditText
 //               view.requestFocusFromTouch();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The offending line is commented out - the `view.requestFocusFromTouch()` method, which was meant to keep the screen from auto jumping to the next text field when the keyboard was hidden and focus lost. On Android 8 this is not happening, but I need to verify with older versions.